# finding the exact latitude and longitude ngCordova geoloaction

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my exact latitude and longitude of my position using this http://mygeoposition.com/  website I am find my position currect

```
(lat-Copy (x,y)13.049517013° 2' 58.26'' N)(long-Copy (x°,y°)80.217491080° 13' 2.97'' E)
```

but my I am getting the lat and long as `(lat-13.082680199999999 & long-80.2707184).`

here is my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/AQ9RzzOx2I3nVS8ix7EQ?p=preview  I just need to show my lat and long in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the lat & long value is showing `(lat-13.082680199999999 & long-80.2707184)` because of my lat-long internet connection and it shows the respected district lat & log values only. So, My code works fine.

After I run my project in my device I got the exact lat & long of current position.